# How to prove that $a + 2 \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} + 3 \sqrt{1+a^{2}} \geq 2 + \sqrt{1+b^{2}}$ for all $a,b >0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

The inequality

> $$a + 2 \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} + 3 \sqrt{1+a^{2}} \geq 2 + \sqrt{1+b^{2}}$$

is related to some computation regarding the Shapley value of a stochastic cooperative game. Though I'm not sure it holds, I suspect it is true for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Do you know how to prove this inequality for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$? Or do you have any hints pointing towards a possible proof?

Comment: Seems straightforward: $2\sqrt {1+a^2}\ge2$ and $2\sqrt {a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{1+a^2}\ge 2b+1\ge\sqrt {1+b^2}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 
$$a + 2 \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} + 3 \sqrt{1+a^{2}} \geq 2b+3\geq b+3\geq2 + \sqrt{1+b^{2}},$$
where the last inequality it's $$b+1\geq\sqrt{1+b^2}$$ or
$$2b\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Thank you! Seems similar to Andrés E. Caicedo's answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, but I wrote it before. ;)

Comment: That's true indeed!